# error 422 When try payment by paypal With Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, paypal, sdk, payment-gateway, payment

When I add a PayPal payment gateway using the Javascript SDK it gives me this error, but the API accesses PayPal
[Error From Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEukK.png)

[API Cells From Paypal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1TQl.png)

This My Code HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <script
    src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=myIDCode"></script>
  <!-- Set up a container element for the button -->
  <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
  <script>
    paypal.Buttons({
      createOrder: function (data, actions) {
        // Set up the transaction details
        return actions.order.create({
          purchase_units: [{
            amount: {
              value: '10.00' 
            }
          }]
        });
      },
      onApprove: function (data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function (details) {
          alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        });
      }
    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

-- Can Anyone Help Me?!, I Try Many Ways without SDK, But It Same Error!!

I expected the payment to be completed successfully

Comment: actions.order.create and actions.order.capture are deprecated and should not be used for any new integrations. See the current integration guide, which involves using 2 backend routes for order creation and capture: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: @PrestonPHX His way used Node.js for Backend, can I use PHP for That? (I searched for other way by php but it same error 422 or error 402)

Comment: The samples are in node.js but you can of course implement the backend routes in any suitable environment, including PHP.

Comment: @PrestonPHX , Do you have code for that ?(use it by php)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.